# Redimensionar un arreglo estático con la función System.arraycopy

Tags: java, array

Necesito redimensionar un arrehlo declarado estático como:

```
array = int array[10];
```

Cuando esta lleno, debo ocupar el `System.arrayCopy` y redimensionarlo con eso.

Comment: puedes complementar tu pregunta con el código que tienes realizado hasta el momento, así podemos evaluar mejor tu problema.

Comment: Hola @yoselin lamentablemente este tipo de preguntas no son bien aceptadas por la comunidad, te recomiendo que visites el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/Tour) y [Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que elabores una pregunta con buena calidad.

Answer (score 1):

no entiendo bien que quieres hacer o porque ese caso, pero si lo que quieres es de un arreglo definido, pasarlo con arrayCopy puedes intentar con esto :

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    a = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
    for (int i : a)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Los parámetros que recibe el método Java .arrayCopy son:

> Array origen Posición inicial del array origen Array destino Posición
>   incial en el array de destino Numero de elementos a copiar del array
>   origen al array destino.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

arraycopy hasta donde se (perdona si me equivoco), te copia el array que selecciones de origen a otro array elegido como destino. Si quieres redimensionarlo a otro tamaño el array, tendrias que crear otro y volcar la informacion. He hecho un metodo y te servirá si es lo que busca en el que utilizo tambien el arrayCopy.

Te pongo la clase a modo de ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = { 8, 1, 4, 14, 5, 7, 9, 11 };

    a = resizeArray(15, a);
}

public static int[] resizeArray(int resize, int[] a) {

    int[] b = new int[resize];

    /* 1ºArg: Array origen,
     * 2ºArg: Por donde comienza a copiar en el origen
     * 3ºArg: Array destino
     * 4ºArg: Por donde comienza a copiar en el destino
     * 5ºArg: Numero de elementos que copiara del origen
     */
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);

    return b;
}
```